# php:changing value of variable in function then change value of that in class

Tags: php, class

I want when running a function  comp_group() in a class and changed data of a variable in my **public $newId**. 
  also changed the variable outside the function for ever
In other words if the class was loaded again default value of $newId is equal to 2.

for example:

```
class Text 
{

    public $newId ;


    public function comp_group()
         {

           $this->newId=2;
         }

}
  public function  maxIdNote()
  {
    return $this->newId;
  }
```

I want change this code to do that when 
Will running the next time  in class $newId=2 in start and before run function comp_group()

i want if i use maxIdNote() in another page  returned  **2**

This is the time
comp_group() function is executed once and
Not be make again running

Comment: Would you please explain in more detail what you are trying to do?  Maybe show an example of the usage and results.